# How to change the date format of a file?

Tags: unix

I need to put the date of a file in this format MM DD HH:MM but I get DD MM HH:MM.

I have already tried to use the command "touch":

```
touch -t 06012342 testDay00
```

But when I use `ls -l` to see the long format of the file the date format is still wrong.

[image: example]

How can I get the correct format?

Comment: A file doesn't have "a date format". It's the configuration of your shell which defines the date format used.

Comment: `man ls`: "--time-style=STYLE +FORMAT;  FORMAT  is  interpreted like in 'date'"

Comment: Likely the `LC_TIME` environment variable can be used.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203975/best-practice-to-customize-date-time-format-system-wide and follow some of the links on the right.

Comment: @JamesBrown what do you mean by "--time-style......." ? Is there any command that I dont know to change the date format in my Shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *to change the date format of a file* when you view the file's date with `ls -l`, use `ls`'s switches to control the output. `man ls` reveales:

```
--time-style=STYLE
       with  -l, show times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso, iso,
       locale, or +FORMAT; FORMAT is interpreted  like  in  'date';  if
       FORMAT  is  FORMAT1FORMAT2,  then  FORMAT1  applies  to
       non-recent files and FORMAT2 to recent files; if STYLE  is  pre‐
       fixed  with  'posix-', STYLE takes effect only outside the POSIX
       locale
```

So:

```
$ touch foo
$ ls -l --time-style=+"%m %d %H:%M" foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 0 07 01 23:50 foo
```

Comment: I have an error when I tried to use `--time-style=...`, I get an **illegal option -- -**. I will try to fix this issue and I think it should be good